# Проверка SNMP Session на PERL

Tags: perl, snmp

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на библиотеке **Net::SNMP** осуществить проверку сессии? Если скрипт смог подключится к коммутатору то продолжает свою работу. Если же подключение не удалось, то тогда он выдает ошибку и продолжает свою работу.
В интернете я нашел только такой вариант:

```
my $snmp_session = Net::SNMP->session(-hostname => $host,-community => $snmp_community,-version => '2c',) or die('Not connect!');
```

Если соединение не осуществилось, то скрипт умирает, что мне не подходит.

Из примеров в интернете смог найти только проверку запроса **get_request**, которая работает по нужному мне принципу. Для проверки сессии, к сожалению, она не подходит.

```
my $test = $snmp_session->get_request(-varbindlist => [$snmp_oid]);
unless (defined $test) {
printf "_ERROR: OID.\n";
}
```

Comment: А кто запретил вместо `die` написать `do_what_you_need_if_not_connected()` ?

Comment: andy.37, а можете более подробно описать? В перле не селен, к сожалению.. `my $snmp_session = Net::SNMP->session(-hostname => $snmp_host,-community => $snmp_community,-version => '2c',) or error(my $error = '1');` Не работает, либо я что то не так понял.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm - Этот вариант используете?

Comment: andy.37, Я использую Active Perl под виндой, стоит именно этот пакет.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Там же есть описание конструктора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $snmp_session = Net::SNMP->session(...);
if ($snmp_session) {
   do_something();
} else {
   do_something_else();
}
```

---

Как вариант:

```
my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(...);
if ($error) {
   process_error();
} else {
   do_common_stuff();
}
```

> This is the constructor for Net::SNMP objects. In scalar context, a reference to a new Net::SNMP object is returned if the creation of the object is successful. In list context, a reference to a new Net::SNMP object and an empty error message string is returned. If a failure occurs, the object reference is returned as the undefined value. The error string may be used to determine the cause of the error.

В скалярном контексте возвращается ссылка на объект Net::SNMP. В списочном контектсте возврращается та же ссылка и пустая строка ошибки. При сбое, ссылка на объект возвращается как `undefined`. Строка ошибки может быть использована для определения причины ошибки. (вольный перевод)

---

Очень похоже на то, что это нормальное поведение. Для любого допустимого адреса в `$error` пусто, а `$session` - определено. Ошибки должны вылезти позже, можно, например, проверить какой-нибудь стандартный OID. Если задать `-hostname => 192.168.20.1000` (к примеру), `$error -> Unable to resolve the UDP/IPv4 address "192.168.20.1000"`, `$session -> undefined`.

Comment: К сожалению у меня всегда выдает значение ** do_something();**, без разницы успешное соединение или не успешное..

Comment: Второй вариант у меня всегда выдает ` do_common_stuff();` в не зависимости от того состоялось соединение или нет. Ипшник к которому я подключаюсь вообще не существует в сети (это для проверки ошибки, возможно это важно).

Comment: А если сделать `print "$session, $error\n";`?

Comment: Это соединение должно быть с ошибкой: `c:\Perl>snmp.pl
Net::SNMP=HASH(0x24c48f0),`, это должно быть без ошибки: `c:\Perl>snmp.pl
Net::SNMP=HASH(0xe248f0),`. Переменная `$error` всегда пустая, в не зависимости от того состоялось соединение или нет.

Comment: Судя по вашему переводу у меня должна быть переменная `$session` пустой, если не состоялось соединение, но она все равно возвращает хэш...

Comment: Могу только подвердить, у себя обнаружил такое же поведение.

Comment: Действительно, ошибку возвращает только уже после отправки get_request. Большое спасибо.

Comment: @Firsim, можно еще предварительно проверять пингом и nmap 161-ого порта...